# Questionning a technique for preloading images (typically used as background images for hover state)

Tags: css

[This technique for preloading several images](http://www.thonky.com/javascript-and-css-guide/css-image-preload) entails the following CSS:

```
#preload_area {
    background-image: url(someimage.jpg);
    background-image: url(someimage2.jpg);
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    display: inline;
}
```

However, will `someimage.jpg` actually be loaded? I would have thought it would simply be ignored hence not loaded after being overriden by the rule with `someimage2.jpg` in the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the first `background-image` would be ignored. However, you can use something similar since [CSS3 supports multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds):

```
background-image: url(someimage.jpg), url(someimage2.jpg);
```

Supported by every broswer since IE8 – http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds